# Show that if $n\neq0$ then $\vert D(n) \vert = 2n \iff n\in\{-2,-1,1,2\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Where $D(n) = \{m\in Z\vert  m\vert n\}$

I have already shown that if $n\neq 0$ then $\vert D(n) \vert \leq 2n$ but I am completely baffled as to how to show equality. I have only just started learning number theory.

This is what I have been doing:

$\vert D(n)\vert= \vert m \vert$ where $m\vert n$ $\implies$ $n=qm$ $\implies$ $m=\frac nq$

$\implies$ $\vert D(n)\vert= \vert \frac nq \vert$ Hence, I need to show that

$\vert \frac nq \vert = 2n \iff n \in \{-2,-1,1,2\}$

But every way I go about this results in $q= \frac 12$ which shows I must be crucially misunderstanding something as q is an integer.

Any help would be very much appreciated, strikes have been ongoing at my university for 3 weeks now so there has been a massive lack of support.

Comment: $|D(n)| = 2n$ means exactly that all the numbers in $\lbrace -n, ..., n \rbrace \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$ divide $n$. Can you take it from here ?

Comment: It might be useful to focus on positive divisors of positive integers, since allowing $-m$ to be included as a divisor just amounts to $m$ being a divisor of $n$.  This has the effect of reducing the size of $D(n)$ by half.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the set of divisors of $n$ is always a subset of $\{-n,-(n-1),\cdots,-1,1,\cdots,n-1,n\}$, so that $$|D(n)|=2n\iff \text{ every positive integer less than or equal to }n\text{ divides }n.$$

Without loss of generality, let's assume $n$ is positive. In particular, if $n>1$, $|D(n)|=2n$ yields that $n-1|n$. Using Bézout's theorem, since $n-(n-1)=1$, it follows that $n-1$ and $n$ are coprime, so the only way that $n-1|n$ is if $n-1=1$, and therefore $n=2$.

That explains why $n=2$ is the only solution greater than $1$. Then you can easily notice that $1$ also works, and extend the same argument to the cases where $n$ is negative.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still very confused, we have only covered the very basics i.e. what divisors are, the properties of divisors and division with remainders, nothing to do with primes. I'm still just getting to ` $q= \frac 12 $ ` from $2n \vert n \implies n = q2n \implies q = \frac 12$`

Comment: Although $D(n)$ is the set of divisors of $n$, nothing guarantees that $|D(n)|$ itself is a divisor of $n$, so your argument to write $|D(n)|=\frac{n}{q}$ is flawed. The idea is that, if $|D(n)|=2n$, then every positive integer less than or equal to $n$ divides $n$. But if you take $n\ge3$, $n-1|n$ means there exists $q\in\mathbb N$ such that $n=q(n-1)$. If $q=1$, the equality obviously does not hold, and if $q\ge2$, then $q(n-1)\ge 2n-2>n$ because $n>2$. In conclusion, if $n>2$ then $n-1$ is never a divisor of $n$, and therefore $|D(n)|<2n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I understand what is being said here except for the original assertion that ` $ \vert D(n) \vert = 2n \iff $ ` every positive integer less than or equal to n divides n. But also, it seems to me that these inequalities still hold for ` $ \vert n \vert = 1$ ` and ` $ \vert n \vert = 2 $ ` I just can't see the equality. If there are any texts you know of that may help me in this area I'd be very grateful for a recommendation. But thank you for your help!